# How to install gcc without internet connection?

Tags: gcc

I am trying to install the software necessary for a wifi adapter on my linux machine. In order to do so I need gcc, which I can't download because I don't have wifi access. I have tried installing from a deb file I got off the debian website and but on a usb, but that never got past "pending installation". I also saw somewhere else recommend downloading from this link (http://www.netgull.com/gcc/old-releases/) but it only allows me to download from the lowest path file, and there is not option for a zip download. I am looking for a way to download all the necessary files for gcc onto a usb.

Comment: Connect your phone using a USB cable.

Comment: Related: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)